# PageMethods breaks when urlrewriting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

I'm using PageMethods inside a javascript function to invoke methods that in codebehind.
It works perfect if i don't use urlrewriting.
If i use it, it breaks this code

```
PageMethods.myMethod(parameters, onSuccess, onFailed);
```

and it's like only refreshing the aspx page. It invokes only page_load.

I used rewriting rule something like that

```
<rewrite url="~/uso/(.+).aspx" to="~/uso/$1.aspx" processing ="stop"/>
```

As you see, I redirected to page itself. However it still breaks it. I use intelligencia rewriter. Do you think it may be related with that urlrewriter module ?

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I found another way to call the WebMethod. I used Webservice.